# @Component annotation still needed on beans that has a FactoryBean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Suppose I have

```
public class MyBean
```

and

```
@Component
public class MyBeanFactory implements FactoryBean<MyBean>
```

I want to inject MyBean using `@Autowired` annotation. In that case, do I still need to annotate MyBean with `@Component`? I thought I should be able to but if I do, spring seems to not use MyBeanFactory to create the bean. If I don't, I can get the get the bean created by factory.

Answer (score 0):

Your factory bean is used to create a bean of type MyBean instantiated according to whatever code you put in your factory bean implementation.

Putting @Component on MyBean will just create a new instance of MyBean and then create a bean from that instance.

If you are using a factory bean to create MyBean then there is no need to put @Component on MyBean.

What are you actually trying to achieve anyway ?